# mount multi shared folder as a big capacity folder on Linux

Tags: linux, mount

If I have 5 machines and they all have second harddisk of `500G`, /dev/sdb1.
Is there any way I can mount the 5 harddisk on /data?

Means the 5 machines share their second harddisk on /data,
and I can store `5*500G` data on /data.

I am thinking about using NFS+AUFS to do this,
or is there a better way to achieve this on Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: don't. you'll have more problems than profit, just use 5 separate mounts.

Comment: Because the 5 servers have different loading,
some need more space and some need less space.
and they automatically store data on /data
So I just thinking is there some way I can take best usage of the 5 harddisks.

Comment: What happens if one of the servers is down? Or more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check out [Gluster](http://www.gluster.com/) (specifically, [distributed volumes](http://download.gluster.com/pub/gluster/glusterfs/3.2/Documentation/AG/html/chap-Administration_Guide-Setting_Volumes.html#sect-Administration_Guide-Setting_Volumes-Distributed)).

Comment: looks like a powerful software, I will try this, thanks a lot :)